# want to run a easy root command by ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I can run normal uptime command on remote linux.
but a root privilege required command is getting error.
what's wrong here ? normally, I have to login remote linux and "sudo su -" then issue the dmidecode command.

```
[root@automation ansible]# ansible test -m shell -a "dmidecode" -c paramiko -k -b
test101.com | FAILED | rc=127 >>
/bin/sh: dmidecode: command not foundnon-zero return code




[root@automation ansible]# ansible test -m shell -a "uptime" -c paramiko -k
SSH password:
test101.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
 21:34:38 up 284 days,  8:24,  2 users,  load average: 0.32, 0.31, 0.35
```

```
[root@automation ansible]# cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory       = /etc/ansible/hosts
host_key_checking = false
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
pattern        = *
forks          = 10
poll_interval  = 15
ask_pass=True
sudo_user      = root
#user           = test
remote_user = test
transport      = smart
#module_lang    = C
gathering = smart
fact_caching = redis
sudo_exe = sudo
timeout = 15
ansible_managed = Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}
deprecation_warnings=False
fact_caching = memory
log_path=/etc/ansible/logfile
command_warnings=False
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
[accelerate]
```

Comment: Why do you *" normally, I have to login remote linux and sudo su -"* when you login to remote as root?

Comment: It is not sufficient to run ansible as root on the local machine, you need to make sure that the ansible instance that runs on the remote machine can run commands as root (e.g. `become: ...`).

Comment: I mean, I can successfully remote login then sudo to root to do any thing. But want here let ansible remote batch do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *" I am a normal user@test and have to "sudo su -" to be a root on remote "test" to do dmidecode "*

The problem is that *"dmidecode command is not found"* by root@test.

> /bin/sh: dmidecode: command not foundnon-zero return code

A: Take a look at what is the *PATH* and where is *dmidecode*

```
[root@automation ansible]# ansible test -m command -a "echo $PATH" -c paramiko -k -b
[root@automation ansible]# ansible test -m command -a "which dmidecode" -c paramiko -k -b
```

You might want to login to *root@test* and find out what is the problem.

Comment: nope, I am a normal user@test and have to "sudo su -" to be a root on remote "test" to do dmidecode command.

Comment: Oh, Dear Sir, you are right, the $PATH is totally different from what I ssh login.
it's like below by using ansible
test101.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
/root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/puppet/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/python3/bin

Comment: Does that mean, in that shell I can't sudo to root ?

Comment: Probably you could, but [Privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general).

Comment: I don't understand, how ansible initial a ssh login ? why the login shell is different ..

Comment: [WARNING]: Platform linux on host test101.com is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change
this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.

Comment: To understand ssh see [ssh – connect via ssh client binary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/ssh.html#ssh-connect-via-ssh-client-binary). To understand paramiko see [paramiko_ssh](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.html#paramiko-ssh-run-tasks-via-python-ssh-paramiko). See [other plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#plugin-list).

Answer (score 0):

Provide the path for dmidecode and provide become in the arguments.

```
ansible test -m shell -a "/path of the file/dmidecode" -c paramiko -k -b --become -u test --ask-become-pass
```

Comment: negative, I tried it and it say ""module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n","

Comment: So I added password prompt,[root@automation ansible]# ansible test -m shell -a "/usr/sbin/dmidecode" -c paramiko -k --become -b -K
SSH password:
but still :module_stdout": "\r\nSorry, user test is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-otptcglytuihjtuwfkqgmnxirfekshns ; /usr/bin/python /home/test/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572964456.82-107930952801582/AnsiballZ_command.py' as root on test101.com

Comment: sure thing, after I login with the user "test" and exec "sudo su -", then I'm the root.

Comment: just tried add -u test. but same error: user test is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-otptcglytuihjtuwfkqgmnxirfekshns ; /usr/bin/python /home/test/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1572964456.82-107930952801582

Comment: User name is my name the_flash, it doesn't matter.